# sorting on basis of lookup number in material-table react

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I want to sort priority column as immediate then urgent then high and so on, but i can sort only ascending or descending on the basis of alphabets,
but I want to sort on the basis of lookup number

```
{ 
  title: "priority", 
  field:"priority",
  lookup: { 1: 'Immediate', 2: 'Urgent', 3: 'High', 4: 'Normal', 5: 'Low' },
}
```

here is a link for the material-table sorting documentation
https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figured it out

```
{ title: "priority", field:"priority",
  // lookup: { 1: 'Immidiate', 2: 'Urgent', 3: 'High', 4: 'Normal', 5: 'Low' },
  render: 
    rowData => 
    rowData.priority == "1" ? <Badge variant="danger">Immidiate</Badge>:
    rowData.priority == "2" ? <Badge variant="warning">Urgent</Badge> : 
    rowData.priority == "3" ? <Badge variant="warning">High</Badge> : 
    rowData.priority == "4" ? <Badge variant="primary">Normal</Badge>:
    rowData.priority == "5" ? <Badge variant="secondary">Low</Badge>:
    <Badge variant="dark">{rowData.priority}</Badge>
},
```

I removed lookup and render it like this